# How to wait for multiple loading element to disappear using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, lambda, webdriverwait, loader

I have a dashboard with several charts. Until a chart is loaded it displays

```
Loading...
```

The page is fully loaded, when in all charts `Loading...` isn't visible anymore.

*`Loading...`* is one class embeded in all chart divs. Each chart has an id that changes with every reload.

```
<div id="loadmask-3379-msgTextEl" data-ref="msgTextEl" class="x-mask-msg-text" role="presentation">Loading...</div>
```

I can easily wait for one element with the line below but don't know how until all have disappeared:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'Loading')]")))
```

How can I implement in Selenium with Python and on Edge an explicit wait until **`Loading...`** disappeared in all charts?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep trying to find the element until none is found.

Comment: Do I have to put the wait into a loop or do you mean this alone waits until all 'loading' have disappeared. I thought it wait's only for the first one.

Comment: you put in the loop which ends when nothing is found. Use find_element function in try statement and break the loop when it raises NoSuchElementException. Or you can use find_elements and check if the returned list is empty. I would go with 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for all the ***loader*** elements to disappear you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using [`selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.none_of(*expected_conditions)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.none_of):

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.none_of(visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'Loading')]"))))
  ```
- Using [`selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.none_of(*expected_conditions)`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.none_of):

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.none_of(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Loading')]")))))
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot and makes sense. Now seems (visibility_of_all_elements_located...) is not accepted: 

NameError: name 'visibility_of_all_elements_located' is not defined

When I'm building the term visiblity is not offered as valid entry. Without the 'none_of' it's accepted

Comment: Just for a quick test can you replace `visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'Loading')]"))` with `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(text(),'Loading')]")))`

Comment: This works. Seems none_of causing the issue.

Comment: Well, my recommendation was on R&D basis. Do you want to say the second option from the updated answer worked? I would have loved to get your feedback and a discussion in the [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: Hello. No the second option results in this error:

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: _This works_: Which approach worked :)